# working php codes in terminal, but not working with browser

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I cannot executed this code on sdk 2.* with browser ;

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset = utf-8');
require 'aws-autoloader.php';
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
require 's3_config.php'; // credentials vs.
$time_start = microtime(true);
#----------------------------------------------------#
$bucket = time()."unique_bucket_id";
  echo "Creating bucket named {$bucket}\n";
  $result = $client->createBucket(array(
  'Bucket' => $bucket
  ));
  // Wait until the bucket is created
  $client->waitUntilBucketExists(array('Bucket' => $bucket));

  echo "Created {$bucket}\n";
#-------------------------------------------------------#
$time = microtime(true)-$time_start;
echo PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL.$time.PHP_EOL;
```

but its working clearly in terminal. 
What should I do for working with browser?
(When I change the codes according to php sdk 1.6.2, then its working with both of terminal and browser. I mean there is no permission problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run from the cli, the home directory is set in the environment as the home directory of the user you are logged in. `/home/your_username`

On web, it's set another home directory, usually the web service's one.
You can check by running `echo getenv('HOME');` both in cli and web and the create the `.aws/credentials` file in the according directories.